# opening a new page and passing a parameter to it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml, dhtml, html-table

I have a JS function that processes XML I GET from a server to dynamically create a table as below

```
// Generate table of services by parsing the returned XML service list.
function convertServiceXmlDataToTable(xml) {
    var tbodyElem = document.getElementById("myTbody");
    var trElem, tdElem;
    var j = 0;
    $(xml).find("Service").each(function() {
        trElem = tbodyElem.insertRow(tbodyElem.rows.length);
        trElem.className = "tr" + (j % 2);

        // first column -> service ID
        var serviceID = $(this).attr("service__id");
        tdElem = trElem.insertCell(trElem.cells.length);
        tdElem.className = "col0";
        tdElem.innerHTML = serviceID;

        // second column -> service name
        tdElem = trElem.insertCell(trElem.cells.length);
        tdElem.className = "col1";
        tdElem.innerHTML = "<a href=javascript:showServiceInfo(" + serviceID + ")>" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</a>";

        j++;
    }); // each service
}
```

where `showServiceInfo` retrieves more detailed information about each service from the server based on the `serviceID` and displays it in the same page as the services table.

So far so good. But, it turns out that I have to display the detailed service information in another page rather than the same page as the table. I have creates a generic `service_info.html` with an empty layout template, but I don't understand how to pass `serviceID` to this new page so that it gets customized with the detailed service info.

How can I do this? Or, is there a better way to handle these situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like:

```
...
...
tdElem.innerHTML = "<a href=javascript:showServiceInfo.html?serivceId=" + serviceID + ">" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</a>"; 
...
...
```

Then the showServiceInfo.html page uses the service ID passed in as part of the QueryString and retrieves the data itself.

Comment: That seems to be the right way to go, thanks. But how would the page retrieve the parameter passed to it in the URL?

Comment: Got it. Used the function from the excellent blog entry here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html